# Javascript (html) - getting a variable to have to same value as an img with .src

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, function

I'm creating a game that displays images, and if the player clicks on the image, a function is called to update the stats (score/correct answers/incorrect answers). 
I've stored the images in an array, and within the update stats function I compare the player's answer (image selected) with the array.
However, no matter whether correct or not, the player's answer is always classed as wrong and they never get any correct answers.

Could somebody please check out my code to see if they can spot any obvious errors. Much appreciated.

```
function displayImgs () {
     for(i = 0; i < allCelebs.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("image"+i).src = fullList[i];
    }
}

function updateStats () {
    Answer = document.getElementById("image"+i); 
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter < selectedImages.length) {
        if (Answer==selectedImages[counter]) {
            score+=50;
            correctAnswers+=1;
        } else {
            score-=20;
            incorrectAnswers+=1;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

And my code for generating the images in html:

```
<script> 
for (count=0;count<16;count++) {
    document.write("<img id='image",count,"' src='blank.jpg' onClick='updateStats();'>"); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is `i` in updateStats ??

Comment: change to `function updateStats ( i ) {` and `onClick='updateStats( count )` ? :-)

Comment: still no luck after passing in the parameters :/

Answer (score 1):

You are not obtaining the correct element in the click event. You can change the generator to this. Note the additional parameter passed to the updateStat function.

```
    for (count=0;count<16;count++) {
        document.write("<img id='image",count,"' src='blank.jpg' onClick='updateStats(",count,");'>"); 
    }
```

And then you will have a reference of which image was clicked

```
function updateStats (index) {
    Answer = document.getElementById("image"+index); 
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter < selectedImages.length) {
        if (Answer==selectedImages[counter]) {
            score+=50;
            correctAnswers+=1;
        } else {
            score-=20;
            incorrectAnswers+=1;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's helped a little, as when I check the debugger it says that playerAnswer is undefined, whereas before, it said 'null'.

Comment: However, the correct answer still doesn't update correctly, I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the line                                                                                          document.getElementById("image"+i).src = fullList[i];                                                 The image is a .src  but Answer isn't, and I'm not sure how to make them contain the same type of value, any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Without a full example i cannot help you more. For example i cannot figure out where you assign selectedImages, allCelebs or fullList variables or what are it's values